# Radio buttons with Paginator (CakePHP)

Tags: cakephp, pagination, radio-button, paginator

I want to have a paginated list in a table and a radio button for each record.

I looked everywhere and I couldn't find anything. I know how to do this with `checkbox` (simply adding `$this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'checkbox'));` of course) but it doesn't work when I change `checkbox` to 'radio'. It seems that radio needs an array as options.

I wonder if there's a way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you loop over the data to create the rows of the table. You'll have to create the radio inputs manually by typing the html then because the HtmlHelper can't know about that you're looping over the data and is not aware of the actual row. If I'm wrong: show the code.